# NullPointerException Error in getFilesDir() Method

Tags: android, android-file

I try to save some data in internal storage on android but I keep getting a NullPointerException I think it has to do with the getFilesDir() I'm using but I'm not sure. Can Some Please help clarify if that is that case and help me write this file to the device. Here the Error message im am getting

```
01-20 22:11:59.020: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 22:11:59.020: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.NullPointerException

01-20 22:11:59.020: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:178)

01-20 22:11:59.020: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at yantz.imageapp4.main.writeElement(main.java:89)

01-20 22:11:59.020: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at yantz.imageapp4.Panel.onTouchEvent(Panel.java:102)
```

---

Here is the oncreate of the main class

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   FrameLayout sv = new FrameLayout(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
     test = new Panel(this);
    test.settest(1)   ;   
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(test);
    sv.addView(ll);
    setContentView(sv);}
```

---

Here my OnTouch method in the panel class

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mainactivity=new main();    
    mainactivity.writeElement(new Element(getResources(),(int) event.getX(),(int)  event.getY()));
        Log.v("Gesture", "is 1 ");   
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
 }
```

---

Here is my writeObject method inside my main class

```
public void writeElement(Element obj){
    Log.v("main", "made it to method writeElement" );
    File f = new File(getFilesDir()+FILENAME);
    try {
fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    ObjectOutputStream objectwrite = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    objectwrite.writeObject(obj);
 fos.close(); 
 Log.v("main", "file was  made File ");

 }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.v("main", "file was not made File not found ");
 } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.v("main", "file was not made File IOException ");
}
}
```

---

manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name="yantz.imageapp4.main" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <activity android:name=".charactors" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="yantz.imageapp4.charactors" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:name=".main2" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black">
        <intent-filter>
<action android:name="yantz.imageapp4.main2" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: which line is line main.java:89?

Comment: have you given FILE read write permission in AndroidMenifest.xml ?

Comment: @ghostbust555 line 89 is the  "File f = new File(getFilesDir()+FILENAME);" line in the code

Comment: @Lucifer  No I didn't give file permissions.I didn't now you had to do that.What you type in to do that.

Comment: Are you directly calling an activity (e.g. activity a= new Activity()) or are you starting it via an intent/other methods that ensure that onCreate() is called? I'm referencing this post with a similar problem http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/fa503d582f443a0e

Comment: @ghostbust555 I dont think im dirctly calling the activity just the method writeElement and my main class sort of has the panel class in the main class shouldn't it still be running.I show you by post my onCreate.Sorry for not post the onCreate before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what's wrong. You can't just write

```
mainactivity=new main();
```

getFilesDir should get the correct context instance but it doesn't now.
Try something like that:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    main.writeElement(new Element(...), this.getContext);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public static void writeElement(Element obj, Context context){
    ...
    File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

Open your AndroidManifest.xml and write following lines after the closing of  tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I add the permission to the AndroidManifest.xml but I came up with the same error as before

Comment: READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - "Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this permission."

Comment: getFilesDir() does not have to do with interal vs. external storage. Please read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html.